# ruby cmd not working in folders rbenv: ruby: command not found

Tags: ruby

ruby cmd works in  the below folder. But when I get into another folder, it wont work.

```
  pwd
 /Users/abc/git/lib

 ruby --version
ruby 2.5.3p105 (2018-10-18 revision 65156) [x86_64-darwin19]
```

When I do the same command , I get error

```
pwd
/Users/abc/git/lib/test

ruby --version
rbenv: ruby: command not found

The `ruby' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.5.3
```

Comment: It is weired but it could be a different .local file inside the test folder. Run `rbenv version` in both folder so we can see if there is a local setting for rbenv.

Comment: you were right. test has different version. once I update it, it worked. I will accept your answer , if you can post it as an answer

Comment: glad you solved it. Posted as answer cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is weired but it could be a different `.local` file inside the test folder. Run `rbenv version` in both folder so we can see if there is a local setting for rbenv.